# #Condor: Binary file not found

Tags: condor

Condor is unable to find the binary file *therm2_events* but the file is there.
Below is the script of job submit file:

```
executable = runevents.sh
output = scheddfiles/output$(ProcId).out
error = scheddfiles/error$(ProcId).err
log = scheddfiles/log$(ProcId).log
RequestCpus = 4
queue 1
```

Bash script lines from the *runevents.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash   
  
function f_script_usage()
{
  echo "This script generates events with the \"therm2_events\" program"
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "runevents.sh [EVENTS_INI] [PPID]"
  echo "runevents.sh [OPTION]"
  echo "  [EVENTS_INI]          settings file for therm2_events; default: \"\""
  echo "  [PPID]                parent's system process ID; default: 0"
  echo "  [OPTION]"
  echo "    -h | --help         this screen"
  echo "This script makes use of global variables TH2_EVENTS_INI_ and TH2_PPID_"
  echo
  exit 0
}

function f_intro()
{
  echo "-=[ runevents.sh ]=-----------------------------------------------"
  echo "- Started at:     $(date +"%F %T %Z")"
  echo "- [EVENTS_INI]    $TH2_EVENTS_INI_"
  echo "- [PPID]          $TH2_PPID_"
  echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
}

function f_error_message()
{
  case "$1" in
    1) ERRORMESS_="ERROR #$1: therm2_events reported error.";;
    *) ERRORMESS_="ERROR #$1: unknown type";;
  esac
  echo "-=[ runevents.sh ]=-----------------------------------------------"
  echo "- $ERRORMESS_"
  echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  exit $1
}
function f_global_variables()
{
  if [ -z $TH2_EVENTS_INI_ ]; then
    if ! [ -z $1 ]; then
      TH2_EVENTS_INI_=$1
    fi
  fi

  if [ -z $TH2_PPID_ ]; then
    if ! [ -z $2 ]; then
      TH2_PPID_=$2
    fi
  fi
}
                                                                                                                                                                       
################################################################################                                                                                                       
# MAIN                                                                                                                                                                                 
################################################################################                                                                                                       
if [ "$1" == "-h" -o "$1" == "--help" ]; then
  f_script_usage
fi
f_global_variables $1 $2

f_intro
if ! ./therm2_events $TH2_EVENTS_INI_ $TH2_PPID_; then
  f_error_message 1
fi

exit 0
```

I tried to generate events by submitting job in Condor.If I run the binary file without Condor then it runs and gives some output in terms of a logfile. The same thing I expect when the job runs in Condor but somehow Condor could not found the file and the error file contains **condor_exec.exe: line 90: ./therm2_events: No such file or directory**.
What is the possible solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to transfer this helper program along with your HTCondor job.  Try adding

```
transfer_input_file = therm2_events
```

to you condor submit file.